# Inflection point could not be a local extreme point?

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima

Why is the statement "**An inflection point can not be a local extreme point?**" wrong? Isn't a local extreme point either a max or a min only? What is wrong here?

Comment: The phrasing of the statement is awkward in itself, and there is an overall lack of context in the question.

Comment: Think of the problem $\min x^3$ s.t. $x\ge 0$ Here $x = 0$ is an inflection point but is also the solution point.

Comment: @Cesareo: Some authors require local extrema to be two-sided. If a local extremum can be one-sided, and an inflection point can also be one-sided, then your counterexample is perfect.

Comment: @AdrianKeister What do you mean by a "one-sided inflection point"?

Comment: @user539887: I don't think they exist, which was sort of my point. The concavity has to *change* at a PoI, which means there has to be function to the left and to the right, making Cesareo's counterexample not a counterexample.

Comment: @Adrian Keister: The precise meaning of "inflection point" varies in the literature (see the papers I cited [in this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159564/hint-request-why-we-can-always-depress-a-cubic-by-centering-it-on-the-y-axis#comment4442183_2159564), for example), and so we probably need to know exactly what definition of "inflection point" the OP is working with. See also this [24 December 2005 ap-calculus post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4160939) (and [this followup](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4164367)) archived at Math Forum.